# Why isViewFromObject() method in PagerAdapter is called too many times?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, android-pageradapter

I am using PagerAdapter to load my views one-by-one. I know `instantiateItem()` method is called to create the view from model/data passed to adapter. And on for the first time `instantiateItem()` will be called 2 times i.e. for 0th and 1st position.

I want to know  `isViewFromObject()` method is called. For where it is invoked and how many times it will be called for the first time, on swiping to next view and on removing and/or adding views into adapter? Because I found that it is being called multiple times.

Below are the logs of adapter method execution.

> 08-31 10:50:55.753 26437-26437/? D/CustomPagerAdapter: instantiateItem item ->0
>
> 08-31 10:50:55.758 26437-26437/? D/CustomPagerAdapter: instantiateItem item ->1
>
> 08-31 10:50:55.760 26437-26437/? D/CustomPagerAdapter: isViewFromObject view tag = 0, object tag = 0, view=object
>
> 08-31 10:50:55.761 26437-26437/? D/CustomPagerAdapter: isViewFromObject view tag = 1, object tag = 0, view!=object
>
> isViewFromObject view tag = 1, object tag = 1, view=object
>
> 08-31 10:50:55.783 26437-26437/? D/CustomPagerAdapter: isViewFromObject view tag = 0, object tag = 0, view=object
>
> 08-31 10:50:55.784 26437-26437/? D/CustomPagerAdapter: isViewFromObject view tag = 1, object tag = 0, view!=object
>
> isViewFromObject view tag = 1, object tag = 1, view=object
>
> 08-31 10:50:55.785 26437-26437/? D/CustomPagerAdapter: isViewFromObject view tag = 0, object tag = 0, view=object
>
> 08-31 10:50:55.848 26437-26437/? D/CustomPagerAdapter: isViewFromObject view tag = 0, object tag = 0, view=object
>
> 08-31 10:50:55.848 26437-26437/? D/CustomPagerAdapter: isViewFromObject view tag = 1, object tag = 0, view!=object
>
> isViewFromObject view tag = 1, object tag = 1, view=object
>
> 08-31 10:50:55.849 26437-26437/? D/CustomPagerAdapter: isViewFromObject view tag = 0, object tag = 0, view=object
>
> isViewFromObject view tag = 1, object tag = 0, view!=object
>
> 08-31 10:50:55.850 26437-26437/? D/CustomPagerAdapter: isViewFromObject view tag = 1, object tag = 1, view=object
>
> 08-31 10:50:55.865 26437-26437/? D/CustomPagerAdapter: isViewFromObject view tag = 0, object tag = 0, view=object
>
> isViewFromObject view tag = 1, object tag = 0, view!=object
>
> isViewFromObject view tag = 1, object tag = 1, view=object
>
> 08-31 10:50:55.866 26437-26437/? D/CustomPagerAdapter: isViewFromObject view tag = 0, object tag = 0, view=object
>
> isViewFromObject view tag = 1, object tag = 0, view!=object
>
> isViewFromObject view tag = 1, object tag = 1, view=object

Comment: why don't you check the android sources to know how many times is it called and for which item?

Comment: The internal Implementation of PagerAdapter may call any of the callbacks multiple times - you code should not be dependent on these callbacks